# What are the int64_t range limits on x86?

Tags: c, gcc

Testing some integer multiplications on x86.

```
int32_t a = 2097152;
int64_t b = a * a;
```

Why does the above `b` evaluate to zero?

Comment: i think you need to cast one of the operands to 64 bit first. try int64_t b = (int64_t) a * a

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What are the int64_t range limits on x86?

[C11 standard 7.20.2.1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.2.1p1) says `[-2^63; 2^63-1]` which is equivalent to `[-9223372036854775808;9223372036854775807]` You can get it by printing `INT64_MAX` and `INT64_MIN`.

> Why does the above b evaluate to zero?

Because the promotion does not take place until the multiplication has been evaluated. The result of `a*a` is of type `int32_t` and when you overflow a signed integer you invoke undefined behavior. What you're doing is essentially this:

```
int32_t a = 2097152;
int32_t tmp = a * a;
int64_t b = tmp;
```

You can get the desired result with:

```
int32_t a = 2097152;
int64_t b = ((int64_t) a) * a;
```

The outer parenthesis is not necessary, but it is important to understand that I'm not talking about `(int64_t)(a*a)` which wouldn't yield the correct result.

Comment: @He3lixxx Of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`int64_t` limits are irrelevant in your example, as the type of `b` comes into play only *after* the `a * a` expression is computed, and the damage is already done.

When performing arithmetic the "usual arithmetic conversions" are performed, i.e. the values are converted to a common type that is at least `int`; in this case, `int32_t` is probably already an `int` under the hood, so the two values are left as they are, and 32 bit multiplication is performed. This overflows the range of `int32_t`, with the result you can see (notice that signed overflow is actually undefined behavior).

To make it operate as intended, you have to first cast at least one of the operands to `int64_t`, so that the multiplication gets performed in 64 bit arithmetic.

```
int64_t b = ((int64_t)a) * a;
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you are multiplying two 32bit values and get a 32bit result.

So actually you you get `(a * a) % 2^32`
since
`2097152 * 2097152 = 4398046511104 = 0x40000000000`
 you get the `0x00000000` portion of your result.

If you want to do a proper 64bit multiplication you have to convert one of the arguments

```
int64_t b = (int64_t)a * a;
```